# How to add filterInput field in amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I got below schema (schema.graphql),

```
type Admin @model @auth(rules: [{ allow:owner }]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}

type Staff @model @auth(rules: [{ allow:owner }]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    admin: Admin @connection
}
```

Now I want to fetch Staffs, filtering out by admin's ID.
But when I ran

```
API.graphql(
graphqlOperation(queries.listStaffs,
    {
        filter: {
            admin: {
                eq: adminId
            }
        }
    } 
))
```

It throws an error below.

`The variables input contains a field name 'admin' that is not defined for input object type 'ModelStaffFilterInput'`

Since there's no filter input field for `admin`. In the AppSync console,

```
input ModelStaffFilterInput {
    id: ModelIDInput
    name: ModelStringInput
    and: [ModelStaffFilterInput]
    or: [ModelStaffFilterInput]
    not: ModelStaffFilterInput
}
```

In this case, how do you add filter input field to the GraphQL schema?
Would you supply any example of `amplify/backend/api/pjname/shema.graphql` ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got this work.
All I had to do was explicitly put the key for the relation.

```
type Admin @model @auth(rules: [{ allow:owner }]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}

type Staff @model @auth(rules: [{ allow:owner }]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    admin: Admin! @connection
    staffAdminId: ID! # this field is needed, for generating filterInput
}
```

Then `amplify push`, which generated schema with `staffAdminId`:

```
input ModelStaffFilterInput {
    staffAdminId: ModelIDInput
    id: ModelIDInput
    name: ModelStringInput
    and: [ModelStaffFilterInput]
    or: [ModelStaffFilterInput]
    not: ModelStaffFilterInput
}
```

And run query like

```
listStaffs(filter: {staffAdminId: {eq: "adminID"}})
```

And this `staffAdminId` is already in the table, so it doesn't affect other than the graphql schema.

I got this from:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/300#issuecomment-475786380